# jquery selector performance - class with or without tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

Just wanted to ask which of the following was the better option to use with Jquery

```
$('#thisontainer div.thisWrapper')
```

or

```
$('#thisontainer .thisWrapper')
```

is the second one faster?

Also I'm interested to know why html tags slow performance when added to Jquery Selectors and I also believe CSS selectors?

thankyou

Comment: why don't you give a try yourself? http://jsperf.com

Comment: Without the tag it would be faster.

Comment: See [this jsperf](http://jsperf.com/selectors-with-or-without-tag) for a breakdown for each variant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do `$('#thisontainer').find('.thisWrapper');`

http://24ways.org/2011/your-jquery-now-with-less-suck/

Comment: It would be slower actually

Comment: Are you sure? I've been advised that find is better than complex nested selectors

Comment: I'm sure - they are not nested, `#thisontainer .thisWrapper` is a trivial native css selector

Comment: @zerkms I guess that also depends on whether `querySelectorAll()` can be used, isn't it?

Comment: @Jack: not in 2013 I suppose

Comment: @TGH Well, that article is 1.5 years old ;-)

Comment: Ok, I guess jQuery version and browser version might make this more difficult to predict then :-)

Comment: @zerkms Just like [this jsperf](http://jsperf.com/selectors-with-or-without-tag) :)

Comment: @Jack: even `var $wrapper = $('.thisWrapper', '#thisontainer');` (http://jsperf.com/selectors-with-or-without-tag/2) sucks. That's weird

Comment: @zerkms It does better when the scope is optimized using getElementById; [proof](http://jsperf.com/selectors-with-or-without-tag/3).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a class attribute do not use it with tag name, just use the class name

Look at this [jspref test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-class-name-vs-tag-classname/5)

Comment: is this the same for CSS as well - better to skip the tags for improved performance?

Comment: @Adam I'm not sure about css, but in jQuery it will be faster

Comment: @Adam from the `tag.class` selector what I understand is it will first get all tags then filter them via the class, `.class` will use the native `getElementsByClassName` and get the elements directly hence the difference

Comment: @ArunPJohny No, it works the other way around; it does `.class` first, then filter on tag.

Comment: @Jack so jQuery will do a inline performance analysis on the selector?

Comment: @ArunPJohny Not sure about jQuery (though I'm sure Sizzle has some optimization), but querySelectorAll() should work according to those rules.

Comment: @Jack since jQuery uses sizzle it is safe to assume it does too

Answer (score 1):

There is a ranking.

http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-selector-performance/

What it is trying to say is that id are fastest, then classes, then tags.

<strike>The reason why tags are slower is that behind the scene browser maps out all the data on a page.  When you say something like this `a.mySweetClass` parses from left to right.  So ALL the `a` tags are grabbed, then out of the A tags, it is reduced to `mySweetClass`.  I have read a much better article and i wish i could find it.  I'll continue to look and i'll also provide you with some better timing graphs shortly.</strike>

CSS Selectors are evaluated from right to left:

My bad:  But here are some interesting results
http://jsperf.com/jquery-tag-vs-class

Comment: From what I remember, CSS selectors are evaluated from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is going to be a significant difference either way.

Rendering html tags and processing css rules or jQuery selectors are expensive tasks and in order to maintain an acceptable performance they have to be used carefully. I have come to find situations when even very simple CSS rules have caused significant performance issues.

So here are some advices:

1. Whenever you create a CSS rule, think about how it will be processed. An animated gif as background of every node will probably slow down the site a lot because the image has to be processed independently for every node: * { background:url(bkg.gif); }
2. Instead of repeating node searches in the whole DOM, search for your nodes in the sections of the DOM tree that you have found already. So instead Of:

   ```
   for(var i=0; i < 100; i++)
     $('#thisontainer .something').somecall();
   ```

   use:

   ```
   var c = $('#thisontainer');
   for(var i=0; i < 100; i++)
     $('.something', c).somecall();
   ```
3. Be careful with the changes you make to the DOM in setInterval or setTimeout calls. Changes to the DOM usually are more expensive than simple variable handling, so instead of storing important values as attributes store them in javascript objects with jQuery's .data()

Comment: `$('.something', c)` could be just `c.find('.something')`.